# Sending Object Arrays as JSON using FormData

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, podio

I am sending a FormData object to an endpoint. A phone number needs to be formatted as this JSON:

`"phone": [{"type":"main", "value":"#"}, ...]` or it gets rejected. A single object with a two-pair of keys and values in an array.

```
const doStuff = () => {
  const formData = new FormData()

  **Have tried below for setting key/value of phone object**

  // Attempt 1
  formData.set('phone', [{ type: 'main', value: '313-555-2121' }])
  // Returns:
  "phone":"[Object Object]"

  // Attempt 2
  formData.set(
    'phone',
    JSON.stringify([{ type: 'main', value: '313-555-2121' }])
  )
  // Returns
  "phone":"[{\"type\":\"main\",\"value\":\"313-555-2121\"}]"

  // Format as single "fields" object and stringify (results in fields: {...stuff}), API needs this.
  const formattedForApi = JSON.stringify({fields: Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())})

  // MAKE POST REQUEST...
}
```

The API errors on both of my attempts above. Complaining of an invalid first value which needs to be "main". Am I missing something with how stringify is affecting the data that is actually being sent?

For those wondering, [the API is Podio](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/add-new-item-22362)

Comment: Why are you even bothering with `FormData` if you're just formatting the entire result as JSON? Could you please link to the API docs?

Comment: @Phil Thank you for calling that out, link is now attached to last line. I may not need FormData itself, though a Map is helpful for .get() and .set() as fields are updated with my setup. Is there another approach I should look at instead?

Comment: Those docs are terrible. There's no REST / HTTP docs, just their own PHP and Ruby SDKs

Comment: That's been most of the struggle so far, not maintained anymore. They have a client library for JS written without imports, making it basically useless. All this does is provide an ez-mode version for authenticating, not formatting. 

[link](http://podio.github.io/podio-js/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into the [PHP SDK code](https://github.com/podio-community/podio-php/blob/master/lib/Podio.php#L231), it seems you're supposed to send the fields as plain old JSON and definitely not double-encoded

```js
const formattedForApi = JSON.stringify({
  fields: {
    phone: [
      {
        type: "main",
        value: "313-555-2121",
      },
    ],
  },
});

fetch(`/item/app/${app_id}/`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: formattedForApi,
  headers: {
    authorization: `OAuth2 ${token}`,
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Sending arrays as JSON in FormData is possible, but it requires encoding the arrays into strings before adding them to the FormData object. Here's an example in JavaScript:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const array = [1, 2, 3];

// Encode the array into a string
const encodedArray = JSON.stringify(array);

// Add the encoded array to the FormData object
formData.append("array", encodedArray);

// Send the FormData object in an HTTP request
fetch("https://example.com/api", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

On the server-side, you can decode the string back into an array and use it as needed. The specific implementation will depend on the server-side language you're using.

Comment: _"it requires encoding the arrays into strings before adding them to the FormData object"_... isn't this exactly what OP is already doing?